# Displaying the Full FileURL after Completed Upload in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, ckfinder

When I use CKFinder (integrated in CKEditor) to upload or browser files, how can I get it to show the full FileURL in the inputbox?

That is, I want: `http://www.mydomain.com/userfile/filename.ext`

but not: `/userfile/filename.ext`.

(I am using CKEditor.NET 3.6.2 and CKFinder 2.2.2 .)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very easy to create image picker using CKFinder !!!
After integration just put this code to create Image Picker

```
<input type="text" name="n_thumb_url" id="n_thumb_url"/>
<input id="n_browseServer" value="Browse Server" type="button">
<script>
function SetFileField(fileUrl) {
    jQuery('#n_thumb_url').val(fileUrl);
}
$("#n_browseServer").on("click", function(){
    var finder = new CKFinder();
    finder.basePath = 'http://localhost/integrated/ckfinder';
    finder.selectActionFunction = SetFileField;
    finder.popup();
});
</script>
```